# Use Bootstrap 3 RC1 in the New MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Microsoft has used Bootstrap in their new ASP.Net MVC 5 template. It's really great. However it uses the version 2.3.1 of it and the Bootstrap guys are [moving towards the 3 version already](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/07/27/bootstrap-3-rc1/). I could just easily rewrite the entire views and the layouts based on the new version but I was wondering if somewhere, someone else has done it (maybe by a long shot the Microsoft folks?).

Comment: In fact Bootstrap 3 was just released yesterday, did you try to replace Bootstrap 2.3.1 (JavaScript + CSS) by version 3 in your MVC 5 project?

Comment: I agree with you. Just looking for a method to overwrite the editorfor() helper functions. By the way, I think the -1 is simply a reflection that this valid point is not formatted in the form of a question that we can answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the rules (that I really appreciate) is to put code here instead of link for my blog post but it's just too many small corrections to put them here.

http://www.ghislainproulx.net/Blog/2013/09/using-bootstrap-3-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-mvc-template

Comment: No problem. I really appreciate your blog post.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a NuGet package [Bootstrap.MVC.EditorTemplates.Sample](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.MVC.EditorTemplates.Sample) that contains a Bootstrap 3 based sample site, plus some additional bootstrap controls and culture-aware validation. This works with the VS 2013 RC MVC5 template.

It uses the Twitter.Bootstrap.Less package instead of the plain bootstrap package, it is best to "uninstall-package bootstrap" from the default MVC 5 site before installing it in the project.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of making Bootstrap 3 work on ASP.NET-MVC 5 project (or any other server side technology) is to put proper css and js files into the project and make Layout file use these.
This is very well covered in the [blog by @Ghislain_Proulx](http://www.ghislainproulx.net/Blog/2013/09/using-bootstrap-3-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-mvc-template).

Then all you have to do is follow the syntax rules of Bootstrap 3 in your Views.
One way to do it is use straight html markup. Another - use custom helpers. @Maarten has a cool open sourced EditorTemplates of these. However, I'd suggest using [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/) as it provides a high level of flexibility.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of TwitterBootstrapMVC and using it for Bootstrap 3 requires a license.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Bootstrap 3 final release is out, and so is Visual Studio 2013 RC and ASP.NET MVC 5 RC, it's confirmed that the RTM of ASP.NET MVC 5 will come with Bootstrap 3 (even though it's not in ASP.NET MVC 5 RC yet).

Until ASP.NET MVC 5 RTM / Visual Studio 2013 RTM, [the post](http://www.ghislainproulx.net/Blog/2013/09/using-bootstrap-3-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-mvc-template) referenced in the accepted answer would be the wya to go.